# How to enable middle-mouse-button-click to paste selected text in VS Code's terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have to use VS Code on Windows and when I open a bash terminal in VS Code, I can select text and paste it with a right-mouse-button-click.
I would like to change that to the middle-mouse-button-click just like it works on macOS and Linux.
Is there a way to set VS Code / Codium like that?

The same problem (no middle-click paste) occurs when using VS Code on macOS, opening a Zsh terminal.

I am using VSCodium version 1.61.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make a feature request at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues.
Because [this code](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/86cc884a9e1742a3fddd4e8c36b20cbf198d7260/src/vs/workbench/contrib/terminal/browser/terminalEditor.ts#L134) checks for `isLinux` and ignores `isMacintosh`.